# Joi conditional validation of a key and its valid values based on another key value

Tags: node.js, joi

I want joi validation for a key `values` in such a way that it depends on the value of another key i.e `type`.

I have an object which looks like:

```
const validValues = {
    banana:['001','002','003'],
    apple: ['111','122','133']
}
```

Here, the schema looks like:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string()
    .valid(...Object.keys(validValues))
    .required()
  })})
```

I want to validate `values` here in such a way that if 'banana' is given as `type` then the `values` should only accept ['001','002','003'] and if 'apple' is given as `type` then the acceptable `values` is ['111','122','133']. Also, the `values` is optional as well.

My payload:

```
{
    "type": "banana",
    "values": ["cvf"]
}
```

This payload should give an error because the the values dont map to the type.

Answer (score 1):

In the above condition, I think we can easily check the type property using the `valid()` method. Regarding the values check, we can use the `switch` option. `switch` is useful when we have `multiple` value to check for the `same key`.

```
Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string().valid('banana', 'apple').required(),
  values: Joi.string().when('type', {
    switch: [
      { is: 'banana', then: Joi.valid('001','002','003') },
      { is: 'apple', then: Joi.valid('111','122','133') }
    ],
    otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
  })
})
```

You can check this result realtime in the given website by copy pasting the above rules.
[Joi Tester](https://joi.dev/tester/)

**Note:** Since the Joi Tester does not support the JS code to test. I have hard coded the values like `apple, banana` and their values, rather than using JS code like Object.keys(validValues)

Comment: Hey, the solution works (just a small tweak of array and not string) but I was wondering if theres a more dynamic approach to it. Would it be possible to look at the type and get the relevant values from the validValues object?

Comment: @SunAns Can you please add one sample example to your above comment ? Regarding the tweak of array and not string, I understood